# Error connecting Remote Oracle database in Node.js

Tags: node.js, macos, node-oracledb

I am new to NodeJS. I am unable to connect remote Oracle database using node-oracledb and getting following error.

ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Now, the twisting part is, using same connection detail, I can able to connect Oracle Remote Database using SQLDeveloper app.

I have install Nodejs using Brew on Mac OS X El Capitan and Oracle instant client 12.1.

I also tried SqlPlus but unable to connect Oracle remote database.

The firewall is also turned off. Following code is working on another Mac OS X El Capitan with same configuration.

```
oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : “phtest",
    password      : "Ahora@dev0000”,
    connectString : “MYSEREVER/AMITDEV"
  },
  function(err, connection)
  {
    if (err) { console.error(err.message); return; }

    connection.execute(
      "SELECT * " +
        "FROM  OT_Category_Master",
      function(err, result)
      {
        if (err) { console.error(err.message); return; }
        res.json(result.rows);
      });
  });
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you are not formatting your credentials properly for the driver, but it's impossible to know w/o you providing some code.

Comment: Small correction: you are not using 'node-oracle' you are using 'node-oracledb'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS X 12.1 Instant Client was patched yesterday to fix a problem connecting to older DBs with case sensitive passwords. The symptom was ORA-01017.  [Re-download Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html) and try again.

I update my [announcement blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/using_oracle_on_os_x) to mention this.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check and get back to you. by the way is there any way to log the exact reason for error ORA-01017.